# Showing that a complex function is nowhere analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

There was a similar question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728881/showing-that-a-function-is-nowhere-analytic) but I'm a bit confused by what "nowhere analytic" means.

In this question, we're given $f(x)=x^2+iy^2$. The first part of the question is to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable at all points on the line $y=x$, which I did by showing that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are both continuous and that $f_y=if_x$ when $y=x$.

For the next part, we had to show that $f(x)$ is nowhere analytic. From the Cauchy-Riemann equations, a function is analytic only if $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. Taking the partials, I got:

$$u_y=-v_x\rightarrow0=0$$
$$u_x=v_y\rightarrow2x=2y$$

Wouldn't this mean that the function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation whenever $y=x$ and is thus analytic along that line? In that case, how is $f(x)$ nowhere analytic?

Comment: I would guess the issue here is the difference between "holomorphic" and "analytic". Being analytic means that there is an open ball on which the function is equal to a power series.

Comment: I see. However, my textbook only offers the two following definitions thus far: (1) f is analytic at z if f is differentiable in a neighborhood of z. (2) f is analytic on a set S if f is differentiable at all points of some open set containing S. How can I use these two definitions to show f is nowhere analytic?

Comment: $f$ is complex analytic iff it is given (locally) by a power series in $z$ which means $f$ and all its derivatives are holomorphic and the Taylor series at $a$ converges for $|z-a|$ small enough. Thus it is enough to show $f$ isn't holomorphic anywhere.  Otherwise note $f(x+iy) = x^2+iy^2,  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x+iy)  =  2x ,\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x+iy)  =  2$. If $f$ was complex analytic somewhere then it would be $f''(z) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(z)= 2 \implies f(z) = z^2+bz+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, does the set $x=y$ contain any open sets in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Since $f$ is only differentiable on $y=x$, which is a closed set, then $f$ is not analytic. Is that reasoning correct?

Comment: Closed sets can have interior points. The point is that $y=x$ has empty interior.

Comment: Okay, I see. Any open set containing $y=x$ would contain points not on the line where $f$ is not differentiable, thus $f$ is not analytic on any sets. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, @A.Zhou, except you should say "any open set containing any point(s) of $y=x$ ..."

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much!