# Prove $|z|^{2}$ is not analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with a proof can someone direct me towards or any help would be appreciated .

I have to prove using the zeros of holomorphic functions ( isolated ) that :

> > $f(z)=|z^{2}| $ , is not $\mathbb{C} $-analytic

I cannot use the following method , [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728881/showing-that-z2-is-nowhere-analytic) :\ which is more simple and clear . Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why you don't want to prove it by "simple & clear method"

Comment: f(z) is function of $z^{*}$ since $|z|^2=zz^{*}$ so it is not analytic

Comment: We were asked to not use Cauchy's equation @FaradayPathak

Answer (score 2):

If $|z|^2$ were $\mathbb{C}$-analytic, then so would $g(z)=|z|^2-1$ be. However, $g$ vanishes identically on $S^1$, which has a cluster point in $\mathbb{C}$. By the identity theorem, we would have $g\equiv 0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Hello , I didn't think about using contradiction thanks @WoolierThanThou

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is analytic and non constant it is an open map, and since the range of $f$ is contained $\mathbb{R}$ which is not open in $\mathbb{C}$ and it is not constant we have a contradiction.